# How can I update the permissions on Cassandra system.log?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, logback, cassandra-3.0

when configured through logback.xml, by default system.log was created with permission set
`-rw-r-----` with cassandra user having ownership. For exporting logs tried updating `-rw-r--r--` to 644 permission, But on logrotation that was reverted by cassandra.

Anyway the privilege for these files can be updated through configuration?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a Cassandra question but a filesystem security issue.

Your server has strict permissions for newly-created files. In Unix, the user file-creation mode mask (`umask`) determines the permissions when files get created -- Logback doesn't set the permissions so it is not configurable through `logback.xml`.

You need to update the default `umask` for the Cassandra user so permissions are not so restrictive. The default `umask` is usually set to `022` so the owner has read/write/execute permissions (`0`), and everyone else has read access (`2`).

The default `umask` is typically configured in the following locations:

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`

You can check the current setting by running:

```
$ umask
```

You can set default `umask` for Cassandra by adding it to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, for example:

```
umask 022
```

If you need assistance, consult your sysadmin team. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!